# When styling with XSLT, is XHTML header legal? Redundant?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

In most examples of an XSLT stylesheet, I see a plain html tag used. Is this because using XML/XSLT will eliminate the point of using XHTML(strict)?

Comment: You can output either HTML or XHTML with XSLT, using [`<xsl:output>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output). So it's your choice, not something that is dictated by the XSLT standard or something. And a quick test shows that, in the case of XHTML, you don't need to specify any xmlns attribute in the html start tag.

Answer (score -2):

XSLT is actually used as a transformation. The HTML that you see in the XSL files are styling, where data will be put.

- XML will hold the data.

  - ie.

    ```
    <root>
      <data>hi</data>
      <data>world</data>
    </root>
    ```
- XSL will style it along with HTML.

  - ie. `<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>`
- XSLT will be the transformation tool, the processor that uses your XML data and XSL stylesheets to create, say for example an HTML file, or a PDF file, or a text file, etc.

The XHTML you call strict is just a eXtensible Hypertext Markup Lanaguage file. It is just a more clean version of HTML.

> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp

Comment: Thank you. In a word, if you see this, would you ever see "html xmlns='..../xhtml'" with the DTD for strict xhtml WITHIN an xls document?

Comment: XHTML isn't a more clean version of HTML, it is HTML4 rewritten to conform to XML instead of SGML.

Comment: Sorry, but "XHTML is a stricter and cleaner version of HTML" straight from w3schools. @gh0stm0nk, in terms of the `xmlns` namespace, I personally wouldn't worry about it. The process of the transformation tools is actually pretty strict (at least for the `xsltproc` parsing tools). Leaving out a `</td>` or having it misspelled will throw an exception compared to that without XSL or XHTML. Furthermore, always good to fiddle with it a bit too. Good luck!

Comment: @tyler that doesn't disprove Lego's remark, rather, it shows that you should never regard W3Schools as any kind of authority.